# In Just Cause 3, is there a way to have jetpack-like wingsuit?

Tags: pc, just-cause-3

In Just Cause 3, the feeling of flying is amazing, but could be better.

Is there a way to be able to fly with the wingsuit indefinitely (have it working like a jetpack or an Iron Man suit, so to say)?

I don't care if this is done via a mod or a DLC to buy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Air, Land, and Sea](https://store.na.square-enix.com/product/294188/just-cause-3-dlc-air-land-sea-expansion-pass-dlc) dlc might have what you are looking for, as it includes a new wingsuit with a rechargeable jet pack on it. The bavarium wingsuit also comes equipped with a machine gun and rocket launcher for extra fun.

See it in action [here](https://giant.gfycat.com/LastingTartGnu.gif) and [here](https://giant.gfycat.com/FineGleefulBallpython.gif).

Comment: The *Air, Land, and Sea* DLC is a bundle of 3 DLC, which is cheaper than if you buy all 3 DLC separately. If you don't want the other 2 DLC, then the jetpack belongs to the *Sky Fortress* DLC.

Comment: Please note that [Gfycat](https://gfycat.com) will shut down on Sept. 1, 2023. This affects the media you included in your post since they were uploaded to Gfycat. I recommend that you edit your post and reupload the media through SE Imgur to avoid losing them. You might need to edit the media to make it ≤ 2 MiB, which is the maximum file size allowed by SE Imgur. See [this post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16826/4797) for more info.